# Issue in Pagination Implementation of Reactjs Data Tables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, react-bootstrap, react-table

I am implementing data Tables in reactjs and I want to implement pagination in them which allows users to select the number of rows they want to see at a time. You can see the Table UI [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SwR7.png). (Ignore the css styling issues).

I am beginner in Reactjs and My code is messed. I am Trying to do a couple of things in order to Pagination work correctly but its not working. I tried to find and implement solution online but didn't get what exactly to do?

Here is my code and **Pagination is not working**. Please help me to find out the possible issues.

**Bookings.js**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import '../static/Bookings.css';
import {BsFilterRight} from "react-icons/bs";
import { Pagination} from "../components/Bookings";
import useFullPageLoader from "../hooks/useFullPageLoader";

let bookings_array = [];    
const Bookings= ()=>{
    const[bookings, setBooking]=useState([]);
    const[search, setSearch]=useState("");
    const[searchColumns, setSearchColumns]= useState(["consultant"]);
    const [totalItems, setTotalItems] = useState(0);
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
    const [itemsPerPage, setItemsPerPage]= useState(2);

    function changeItemsPerPage(e){
        setItemsPerPage(e.target.value);
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        loadUsers();
    }, []);

    useEffect(()=>{
        if(search.length){
        setBooking(
                bookings_array.filter(Booking =>
                    searchColumns.some(
                        (column)=> Booking[column].toString().toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
                    )
                )
            )
        }else{
            setBooking(bookings_array)
        }
        
        setTotalItems(bookings.length);

    }, [search, bookings]);

    useEffect(()=>{
        setBooking(
            bookings_array.slice(
                (currentPage - 1) * itemsPerPage,
                (currentPage - 1) * itemsPerPage + itemsPerPage
            )
        )
    }, [currentPage, itemsPerPage])


    const loadUsers= async()=>{
        const result =await axios.get("http://localhost:3001/Bookings");
        bookings_array=result.data.reverse();
        setBooking(bookings_array);
    };

    const deleteUser=async id => {
        await axios.delete(`http://localhost:3001/Bookings/${id}`);
        loadUsers();
    }

    const columns= bookings[0] && Object.keys(bookings[0]);
    return(
        <div className="Booking-page-container">
            <h2 className="text-center mb-4">Bookings Page</h2>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped border shadow">
                <thead className="thead-search-filter">
                <select value={itemsPerPage} onChange={changeItemsPerPage}>
                    <option value={2}>2</option>
                    <option value={4}>4</option>
                    <option value={6}>6</option>
                    <option value={8}>8</option>
                </select>
                <Pagination
                    total={totalItems}
                    itemsPerPage={itemsPerPage}
                    currentPage={currentPage}
                    onPageChange={page => setCurrentPage(page)}
                />
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col" colSpan={6}>
                            <BsFilterRight/> &nbsp;
                            <input className="search-field-input"
                                placeholder=" Search....."
                                onChange={e=>setSearch(e.target.value)}
                            /> 
                            {
                                columns && columns.map(column=> <span>
                                <input type="checkbox" checked={searchColumns.includes(column)}
                                    onChange={(e)=>{
                                        const checked= searchColumns.includes(column)
                                        setSearchColumns(prev=>checked
                                            ? prev.filter(sc=>sc!== column)
                                            : [...prev, column]
                                        );
                                    }}
                                />
                                    &nbsp;{column}&nbsp;
                                </span> 
                                )
                            } 
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
          
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">#</th>
                        <th scope="col">Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Consultant</th>
                        <th scope="col">Email</th>
                        <th scope="col">Phone</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {bookings.map((Booking,index)=>(
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">{index+1}</th>
                            <td>{Booking.name}</td>
                            <td>{Booking.consultant}</td>
                            <td>{Booking.email}</td>
                            <td>{Booking.phone}</td>
                            <td>
                                <Link class="btn btn-primary mr-2" to={`/Bookings/view/${Booking.id}`}>View</Link>
                                <Link class="btn btn-outline-primary mr-2" to={`/Bookings/edit/${Booking.id}`}>Edit</Link>
                                <Link class="btn btn-danger" onClick={()=>deleteUser(Booking.id)}>Delete</Link>
                            </td>
                        </tr>   
                    ))}
                </tbody>
                {console.log(totalItems)}
                {console.log(itemsPerPage)}
            </table>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Bookings;
```

Here is the **index.js of Pagination** imported from "../components/Bookings"

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useMemo } from "react";
import Pagination from "react-bootstrap/Pagination";

const PaginationComponent = ({
    total = 0,
    itemsPerPage = 10,
    currentPage = 1,
    onPageChange
}) => {
    const [totalPages, setTotalPages] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (total > 0 && itemsPerPage > 0)
            setTotalPages(Math.ceil(total / itemsPerPage));
    }, [total, itemsPerPage]);

    const paginationItems = useMemo(() => {
        const pages = [];

        for (let i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
            pages.push(
                <Pagination.Item
                    key={i}
                    active={i === currentPage}
                    onClick={() => onPageChange(i)}
                >
                    {i}
                </Pagination.Item>
            );
        }

        return pages;
    }, [totalPages, currentPage]);

    if (totalPages === 0) return null;

    return (
        <Pagination>
            <Pagination.Prev
                onClick={() => onPageChange(currentPage - 1)}
                disabled={currentPage === 1}
            />
            {paginationItems}
            <Pagination.Next
                onClick={() => onPageChange(currentPage + 1)}
                disabled={currentPage === totalPages}
            />
        </Pagination>
    );
};

export default PaginationComponent;
```

Comment: Needs more focus, you've just said "it doesn't work" and dumped all your code. What **specifically** is the issue?

Comment: i did console.log and the value of totalItems and itemsPerPage is coming correct. But when I click the Pagination numbers 1,2,3 etc. It doesn't work.